Vue 3 rerun compute when element added to array
I have an object of documents that I manage by id within my composable, while to the outside revealing a computed (derived, readonly) state:
const state = reactive({})

export const useDocs = () => {
  return {
    create: doc => { state[doc.id] = doc },
    read: computed(() => Object.values(state)),
    update: (id, val) => {
      Object.assign(state[id], val)
    },
    delete: (id) => { delete state[id] },
  }
}

However, I can't get computed to rerun, without explicit refresh, which I'd like to avoid as I think there must be a valid full-reactive solution to this.
const { create, read } = useDocs()

watch(() => read, docs => {
  console.debug('change detected') // runs only initially
})

// ... later
create({ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }) // not reflected in watcher

I'd also like to avoid any refs to keep it composable across Templates.

An immediate solution to your reactivity problem would be to add deep and immediate to the watcher
watch(() => read, docs => {
  console.log('change detected !!!');
}, { deep: true, immediate: true})

An even better and standard solution is to use a pinia store for managing shared state across your templates
Instead of your composable use a pinia store
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

export const useDocsStore = defineStore('docs', () => {
    const state = ref({})

    const create = (doc) => {
        state.value[doc.id] = doc
    }

    const read = computed(() => Object.values(state.value))

    const update = (id, val) => {
        Object.assign(state.value[id], val)
    }

    const deleteDoc = (id) => {
        delete state.value[id]
    }

    return {
        create,
        read,
        update,
        delete: deleteDoc,
    }
})

And in you templates use it like this:
import { useDocsStore } from "./stores/test"
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const { create } = useDocsStore()
const { read } = storeToRefs(useDocsStore())

You won't even need a watcher the state is reactive from the read getter

The problem that () =>read returns a reference to the computed itself and since it's not changed the watch is silent, just watch the computed itself, Vue reacts to its value's changes:
watch(read, docs => {
  console.debug('change detected') // runs only initially
})

